# Как составить запрос, чтобы Null заменялись на "Не заполнено"?

Tags: sql, excel

У меня есть макрос, который выкачивает массив данных из Excel файла, через рекордсет.
Выкачка происходит при помощи следующего запроса (все работает):

```
squery1 = "Select F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, replace(F8,"" "",""""), F9, F10, F11 " & _ " from [" & Replace(Replace(Replace(oRts.Fields("table_name").Value, ".", "#"), "$", ""), "'", "") & "$A:" & "AE" & "] " & _ "where F2 is not null and F2 not like 'Наименование документа%' and F2 not like '2%' and  F3 is not null;"
```

В столбце F10 исходные данные могут быть не заполнены (т.е. Null). Необходимо изменить запрос таким образом, чтобы при выгрузке данных в колонке F10 значения Null автоматически заменялись на "Не заполнено".
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: в sql это обычно делается с помощью `coalesce(F10,'не заполнено') as F10`, как это будет работать применительно к экселю хз

Comment: Попробуйте так nz(F10,'не заполнено').

Comment: squery1 = "Select F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, replace(F8,"" "",""""), F9, F10, F11 " & _ " from [" & Replace(Replace(Replace(oRts.Fields("table_name").Value, ".", "#"), "$", ""), "'", "") & "$A:" & "AE" & "] " & _ "where F2 is not null and F2 not like 'Наименование документа%' and F2 not like '2%' and  F3 is not null and nz(F10, 'не заполнено';" получается так?

Comment: nz(F10,'не заполнено') не получилось, эксель ругается что функция "nz" - Not Defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил так

```
squery1 = "Select F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, replace(F8,"" "",""""), F9, IIF(ISNULL(F10),""Не заполено"",F10), F11 " & _
                                " from [" & Replace(Replace(Replace(oRts.Fields("table_name").Value, ".", "#"), "$", ""), "'", "") & "$A:" & "AE" & "] " & _
                                "where F2 is not null and F2 not like 'Наименование документа%' and F2 not like '2%';"
```

В селекте написал IIF(ISNULL(F10),""Не заполено"",F10)

Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В выражении select

```
case when f10 is null then 'Не заполнено' else f10 end
```

Comment: Написал так                                 squery1 = "Select F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, replace(F8,"" "",""""), F9, case when f10 is null then 'Не выбрано' else f10 end , F11,  " & _
                                " from [" & Replace(Replace(Replace(oRts.Fields("table_name").Value, ".", "#"), "$", ""), "'", "") & "$A:" & "AE" & "] " & _
                                "where F2 is not null and F2 not like 'Наименование документа%' and F2 not like '2%';" Не работает, вылетает Runtime error Unrecognized keyword WHEN

Comment: А какая среда исполнения?

Comment: Эксель.  При помощи рекордсета формируется массив данных  (т.е. квайри обращается к другому excel файлу с исходными данными)